# Multiple VizFrames in a view

Tags: javascript, sapui5

how can I use multiple VizFrames or multiple charts in a view?

I have this code:

```
<viz:VizFrame xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" id="oVizFrame" busy="false" busyIndicatorDelay="100" visible="true" width="100%"
                uiConfig="{ 'applicationSet': 'fiori' }" vizType="line" legendVisible="true" vizProperties="{ title: {text : '', visible : false}}">
                <viz:dataset>
                    <viz.data:FlattenedDataset xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data" data="{/policy_kilometers_driven}">
                        <viz.data:dimensions>
                            <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="{i18n>months}" value="{month}"/>
                        </viz.data:dimensions>
                        <viz.data:measures>
                            <viz.data:MeasureDefinition group="1" name="{i18n>km_driven_in_month}" value="{km}"/>
                        </viz.data:measures>
                    </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                </viz:dataset>
                <viz:feeds>
                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" id="value1" uid="primaryValues" type="Measure"
                        values="{i18n>km_driven_in_month}"/>
                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="{i18n>months}"/>
                </viz:feeds>            </viz:VizFrame>             <viz:VizFrame xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" id="oVizFrame2" busy="false" busyIndicatorDelay="1000" visible="true"
                uiConfig="{ 'applicationSet': 'fiori' }" vizType="pie" legendVisible="true">
                <viz:dataset>
                    <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{/book}" xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data">
                        <viz.data:dimensions>
                            <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Item Category" value="{Item Category}"/>
                        </viz.data:dimensions>
                        <viz.data:measures>
                            <viz.data:MeasureDefinition group="1" name="Revenue" value="{Revenue}"/>
                        </viz.data:measures>
                    </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                </viz:dataset>
                <viz:feeds>
                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" id="value2" uid="size" type="Measure" values="Revenue"/>
                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" uid="color" type="Dimension" values="Item Category"/>
                </viz:feeds>            </viz:VizFrame>
```

The problem is, that the second VizFrame is never rendered, the first one works fine. If I remove the first frame the secon one is rendered just fine.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Did you change id? Also you can check browser console log.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Yes, I did, the console doesn't throw any errors, can you point me to a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `VerticalLayout` is what you want ?

Please have a look at [VizFrames](https://plnkr.co/edit/4DJG98T6rBLI5sXjXwNs?p=preview) and check lines 195 to 203.

Comment: This seems to do the trick when generating vizframes using js code. However it still does not workusing xml layouts. I guess I will have to use js then.

Comment: Did you check the VerticalLayout example in https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.VerticalLayout/preview ?